# kafka Missing required configuration "zookeeper.connect" which has no default value

Tags: apache-kafka

I setup kafka cluster in vm.

but i have a problem.

My kafka version is kafka 2.11-0.0.0

```
 $ bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties 
[2017-01-31 09:15:55,216] FATAL  (kafka.Kafka$)
org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration "zookeeper.connect" which has no default value.
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:148)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:49)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:56)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:702)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig$.fromProps(KafkaConfig.scala:691)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable$.fromProps(KafkaServerStartable.scala:28)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:58)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
```

please help me .

my zookeeper.properties (down)

---

### zookeeper.properties

```
dataDir=/home/kafka01/zookeeper-data
# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181
# disable the per-ip limit on the number of connections since this is a non-production config
maxClientCnxns=0
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
server.1=kafka01:2888:3888
server.2=kafka02:2888:3888
server.3=kafka03:2888:3888
```

### server.properties

```
zookeeper.connect=kafka01:2181,kafka02:2181,kafka03:2181
```

what is the problem??

Answer (score 13):

You are trying to start a kafka server but you are passing the wrong config file.

Usually you want to start a kafka server using the following command:

```
./kafka-server-start.sh ../config/server.properties
```

And is in this file where you specify the address of the zookeeper:

```
zookeeper.connect=kafka01:2181,kafka02:2181,kafka03:2181
```

The quickstart guide in the kafka official documentation is quite good, I recommend you to have a look at it. You can find it [here](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart).

Answer (score 9):

You are trying to start kafka server with zookeeper config properties file and that's why you are getting the above error.

Use the commands below instead:

Zookeeper:

```
.\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties
```

Kafka:

```
.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties
```

Answer (score 6):

You stared the wrong script. It should be: 
`bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties`

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways you can start Kafka server:

1. Start the zookeeper server separately(on your local or another machine)
2. Start the zookeeper server which is embedded with Kafka server (kafka_2.12/libs/zookeeper-3.4.13.jar)

**In first case:**
I am assuming you have started the zookeeper server already and that is running on localhost:2181

So now you are good to start kafka server using following command

```
bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat ..\..\config\server.properties
```

In server.properties file you have to tell Kafka server where is/are the zookeeper(s) running. Using property:

```
## zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 [default]
zookeeper.connect=zk1:2181, zk2:2181, localhost:2181
```

**In second case**

Start the zookeeper first (embedded with the Kafka server)

```
bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat ..\..\config\zookeeper.properties
```

Then, start the Kafka server:

```
bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat ..\..\config\server.properties
```

Comment: I had somehow overridden my server.properties file. this go me on the rite track, thanks. quick google search later, and all good "kafka server.properties example"

Answer (score 1):

This is the error because there is an issue with your command.

To start zookeeper run -

```
zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

To start server run -

```
kafka-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the zookeeper with:

```
zookeeper-server-start.sh ~/kafka/config/zookeeper.properties
```

Then you need to start the kafka-server using:

```
kafka-server-start.sh ~/kafka/config/server.properties
```

Now your kafka will run smoothly